# Connect to something running on VMWare Fusion host from guest

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm running an elasticsearch server on my Mac and would like to connect to it from Windows 10 running in VM Ware fusion. I have my adapter running in Bridged mode. Everything I read seems to say I should just be able to use the Mac IP address to connect, but it's not working. I have firewalls turned completely off on both the Mac and Windows. I'm trying to access Kibana from Windows, so doing http://192.168.x.x:5061 from Windows browser, keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome. I'm able to ping the IP from the guest, so clearly it can see the host, but something is blocking the connection. I tried forwarding port 5601 on my router, that didn't work either. I do also notice that trying to use http://192.168.x.x:5061 on the Mac itself doesn't work either, which I think may be the source of the problem, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I changed Kibana config file to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. I thought binding to localhost or 127.0.0.1 automatically made it also include the LAN IP, but you learn something new every day...

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't on the VM but your elasticsearch config ...  if you cannot connect to it either with the Mac or the VM, it means that it is elasticSearch that's the issue.